# Wie sagt man »to be back to normal«?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german, expression

> Meine Frau und ich hatten einen Streit und jetzt sind wir zur Normalität zurückgekehrt.

My wife and I had a fight, but now we are back to normal.

Ich weiß nicht, ob dieser Ausdruck zu diesem Kontext passt. Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Comment: Wirklich fight = Streit? Ich hätte das so übersetzt: Fight = Kampf; Streit = quarrel. Unter *fight* verstehe ich eine körperliche Auseinandersetzung, die häufig sogar mit Waffen, zumindest aber mit Faustschlägen ausgetragen wird. Ein Streit ist aber eine rein verbale Auseinandersetzung, bei der auch Geschirr und Mobiliar zu Bruch gehen können. Sogar Schläge können in einem Streit ausgeteilt werden. Aber bei einem *fight* geht es meiner Ansicht nach darum, den Gegner **körperlich** zu besiegen. Bei einem Streit will man, dass die eigene **ideelle** Überzeugung anerkannt wird.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Im (US-)Englischen ist "fight" absolut üblich für einen Ehekrach o.ä. Damit ist keine Form der Gewalt assoziiert. Ein "quarrel" kann dagegen häufig eine langfristige Sache sein, wie ein sich über Monate hinziehender Nachbarschaftsstreit. Der englische Satz ist absolut idiomatisch. (Und wenn ich das richtig verstanden habe, ist OP aus den USA...)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Und umgekehrt ist ein Streit im Deutschen auch oft gewalttätig (Streitmacht, Streitaxt, Streitkräfte, die Streithanseln trennen, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, if “Streit” really is the best translation for “fight”, but let's suppose it is. (I would translate “fight” as “Kampf”, and “Streit” as “dispute” or “quarrel”). But if it really was a verbal conflict and not a physical confrontation, then your translation is correct, but it sounds a little bit like an officers formal speech.

> Meine Frau und ich hatten einen Streit und jetzt sind wir zur Normalität zurückgekehrt.

I would prefer a more free translation:

> Meine Frau und ich hatten einen Streit, aber jetzt ist alles wieder normal.
>   My wife and I had a dispute, but now everything is normal again.

Also possible, but not my favorite, since it also sounds like an officer's speech:

> Meine Frau und ich hatten einen Streit, aber jetzt verhalten wir uns wieder normal.
>   My wife and I had a dispute, but now we behave normal again.

Also a good way to say it is this:

> Meine Frau und ich hatten einen Streit, aber jetzt ist alles wieder wie früher.
>   My wife and I had a dispute, but now everything is as it was before.

My favorite:

> Meine Frau und ich hatten einen Streit, aber jetzt vertragen wir uns wieder.
>   My wife and I had a dispute, but now we get along well again.

Also possible:

> Meine Frau und ich hatten einen Streit, aber jetzt ist alles wieder gut.
>   My wife and I had a dispute, but now everything is fine again.

Comment: Wie @Stephie oben schon schrieb, ist mit fight in diesem Fall keine körperliche Auseinandersetzung gemeint. “We had a fight” ist ein sehr häufig zu hörender Satz und bedeutet „Wir haben uns gestritten“. Bedenke, dass das deutsche Wort Streit ursprünglich auch Kampf bedeutet, wie in Streitwagen oder Streitaxt.

Answer (score 8):

Das Problem liegt darin, dass

> back to normal

ein **Idiom** ist und damit *besser nicht wörtlich übersetzt werden sollte*. (Außer, die Zielsprache benutzt dasselbe Bild, was hier nicht der Fall ist.)

Damit muss man eine Formulierung finden, die mit anderen Worten eine vergleichbare Bedeutung vermittelt.

*back to normal* kann unterschiedlich verstanden werden:

- den Zustand der Beziehung beschreibend:

  > … aber jetzt ist alles wieder wie immer.<sup>(1)</sup>
  >   … aber jetzt ist alles wieder gut.
  >   … aber jetzt ist wieder alles wie vorher.
  >   … aber jetzt ist alles wieder in Ordnung.
  >   …
- das Verhältnis der Beteiligten beschreibend:

  > … aber jetzt vertragen wir uns wieder.
  >   … aber jetzt haben wir und wieder versöhnt.
  >   … aber jetzt sind wir uns wieder einig.

Alle diese Formulierungen sind möglich und gebräuchlich. <sup>(1)</sup> ist zwar die Variante, die dem Original am nächsten kommt, aber im Deutschen werden eher die etwas "positiveren" Formulierungen wie *alles gut* oder *alles in Ordnung* benutzt.